# API: why don't Python arrays have a sort method?

Tags: python, api, sorting

I know about the `sorted()` built-in function. This is an API design question, not a how-to question. I am wondering why the `list` type has a `.sort()` method to sort its contents in-place, but other mutable sequence types like `array.array` and `bytearray` do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort codebase (used by both `sorted()` and `list.sort()` works exclusively with `list` object, and is geared towards sorting python *objects*; items that can implement custom special methods that dictate ordering.

As such, that code is not readily reusable for the `array.array` and `bytearray` types, which deal exclusively in homogenous C type data.

Instead, you'd need to implement a dedicated sorting method for these types, taking advantage of the fact you are basically dealing with basic C types here. And no one has done this yet, which is really the *only* reason these types have no dedicated `.sort()` methods.

The work-around is to use `sorted()` and re-cast as the original type:

```
a = array.array(a.typecode, sorted(a))
b = bytearray(sorted(b))
```

The numpy `ndarray` type does have a [`.sort()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html); perhaps you should use that library instead if you need to do a lot of sorting.

Comment: Excellent answer! I was looking for the Python core developer perspective and that's what you gave us. Thank you very much, Martijn!

Comment: Note: I am *not* a Python core developer. :-)

Comment: OK, you are not a _Python_ core developer, _just_ a Zope and Plone core developer ;-)